# How do I format parameters for PyGreSQL?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, pygresql

I am using PyGreSQL to execute queries against my DB.  I need to insert the values to be matched at runtime, but the parameters are not being into the query correctly.  If my query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM Database
WHERE job_level = ANY(:job_level)
AND job_family = ANY(:job_family)
AND cost_center = ANY(:cost_center)
```

And I wish to use parameters

```
{'cost_center': '*',
 'job_family': 'SDE',
 'job_level': ['5', '6', '4', '7'],
}
```

How do I correctly insert these values via

```
cursor.execute(query, parameters)
```

I have tried:
Not using the ANY operator, but just using IN. This fails with

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
LINE 4:                 WHERE job_level IN :job_level
```

Using %(job_level)s syntax instead of the :job_level.  This fails with

```
ProgrammingError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ANY"
LINE 4:                 WHERE job_level IN ANY(ARRAY['5','6','4','7'...
```

So how do I properly combine the placeholders in the query with the parameters to match all three cases here, a single value, a list of values, and a wildcard matching an entire column?

Comment: Reading the docs [ANY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.30.16) would be a good start.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not really the issue.  If you start by reading the error messages, you can see that the issue is the pgdb library not correctly substituting in the values from the dictionary.  Do you know how to format placeholders/parameters within PyGreSQL?

Comment: *Using %(job_level)s syntax ...* is the correct placeholder method for pulling from a `dict` and `ANY(ARRAY['5','6','4','7'...` shows it did the correct thing. The issue is `WHERE job_level IN ANY(`. That should be `WHERE job_level = ANY(`. That is why I pointed you at the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through much trial and error, I have found the correct combination of placeholders and parameter formats to match all my use cases: single values, wildcards for an entire column, and lists of individual values.  This may not be the only solution, but it works.

Placeholders in the query should be formatted using %()s syntax, inside the ANY operator:

```
query = '''
SELECT *
FROM Database
WHERE job_level = ANY(%(job_level)s)
AND job_family = ANY(%(job_family)s)
AND cost_center = ANY(%(cost_center)s)
'''
```

Single and multi-value parameters need to be formatted as *lists* (for single values, that's probably a side effect of using ANY).  For wildcard matches, you can use the name of the column itself, just as with the IN operator, but this column name must be wrapped in the `pgdb.Literal()` function.  Thus, to match my example selection criteria:

```
{'cost_center': '*', # All cost centers (wildcard)
 'job_family': 'SDE', # Only this single job family
 'job_level': ['5', '6', '4', '7'], # Any of these multiple job levels
}
```

The complete parameter dictionary for my example should be formatted as:

```
parameters = {
'cost_center': [pgdb.Literal('cost_center')],
'job_family': ['SDE'],
'job_level': ['5','6','4','7']
}
```

Which can be safely executed with `cursor.execute(query, parameters)`

This will allow matching of single values, multiple values, and wildcard matches.

Answer (score 1):

The following example code shows how to do this with PyGreSQL.

### Some remarks upfront:

- It looks like your table is called `database`. You should rename it, because `database` is a [keyword in SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html), and database objects are different from table objects, so it can be confusing to read such SQL. In the example I called the table `jobs`.
- You are using `*` as wildcard, but SQL uses `%` instead. You can also use regular expressions in PostgreSQL, but then you need to write `.*` instead of `*`. They also have a different syntax. See [Pattern Matching](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html) for the available options. In the example I used `%` as pattern with `LIKE`.
- Of course, since `*` (`%`) matches any value, you can also simply remove that comparison from the WHERE clause in this case.

### Example using the DB API 2 of PyGreSQL

```py
import pgdb

con = pgdb.connect(...)  # fill in connection parameters
cur = con.cursor()

query_string = '''
SELECT * FROM jobs
WHERE cost_center LIKE %(cost_center)s
AND job_family = %(job_family)s
AND job_level = ANY(%(job_level)s)
'''

parameters = dict(
    cost_center='%',
    job_family='SDE',
    job_level=['5', '6', '4', '7'])

rows = cur.execute(query_string, parameters)

for row in rows:
    print(row)

cur.close()
con.close()
```

### Example using the classic API of PyGreSQL

```py
import pg

db = pg.DB(...)  # fill in connection parameters

query_string = '''
SELECT * FROM jobs
WHERE cost_center LIKE %(cost_center)s
AND job_family = %(job_family)s
AND job_level = ANY(%(job_level)s)
'''

parameters = dict(
    cost_center='%',
    job_family='SDE',
    job_level=['5', '6', '4', '7']
)

query = db.query_formatted(query_string, parameters)
rows = query.namedresult()

for row in rows:
    print(row)

db.close()
```

### Using a parameter tuple instead of a dict

Both APIs also allow passing parameters as tuples instead of dicts. But dicts are more descriptive, allow reusing parameters in several places in the query, and you do not need to care about the order of the parameters. So I recommend using tuples only for very simple queries.

When using tuples, the `query_string` and the `parameters` should loke like this:

```py
query_string = '''
SELECT * FROM jobs
WHERE cost_center LIKE %s
AND job_family = %s
AND job_level = ANY(%s)
'''

parameters = ('%', 'SDE', ['5', '6', '4', '7'])
```

### Using bind parameters directly

The classic API also allows using unformatted (raw) queries with bind parameters `$1`, `$2` etc. directly as they are written in PostgresQL.

For simple data types this works just like passing tuples as above, but other data types like arrays need to be adapted manually. This can be done as follows:

```
query_string = '''
SELECT * FROM jobs
WHERE cost_center LIKE $1
AND job_family = $2
AND job_level = ANY($3)
'''

adapt = pg.Adapter(db).adapt

parameters = ('%', 'SDE', adapt(['5', '6', '4', '7']))

query = db.query(query_string, parameters)
rows = query.namedresult()
```

However, the recommended usage is with formatted querys, where PyGreSQL automatically adapts input and typecasts output.

In most cases, like when passing a list, PyGreSQL can guess the corresponding type in the database, like array in this case. For more exotic data types, you must specify the database type of the parameters explicitly in the `adapt` or `query_formatted` methods. Another way to adapt parameters is wrapping them as type objects, which is also supported in the DB API 2.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  My database isn't actually named database, that's a filler in the pseudo query.  Unfortunately, your solution doesn't work for my use case because you've customized the operators.  My criteria are generated at runtime.  Any of them could be wildcards, arrays or scalars.  Do you know how to accomplish this with uniform operators?

Comment: Ok, now the way you phrased your question makes more sense to me. The wildcard was not meant to represent pattern matching in the database, but to indicate that you want to ignore that parameter completely.

You can implement this kind of behavior in a function that dynamically creates the query string, depending on the passed parameters.